# Saving Firefox (or other applications) windows to open up verbatim on next reboot

Tags: windows-7, firefox, restore, session-restore, window-restore

On Windows 7 Home Premium, I sometimes need to reboot my system, but I don't want to lose the URLs in the various Firefox open windows and tabs. Basically, I would like to save the layout of the firefox windows so that upon finishing the reboot process, when I relaunch firefox, I can restore the saved state of windows and tabs. The same might also go for other running applications before rebooting.

To achieve this, I usually resort to killing Firefox, rebooting, and then restoring the windows from the "Well, this is embarrassing." window that says "Firefox is having trouble recovering your windows and tabs. This is usually caused by a recently opened web page." when I relaunch Firefox, and I press the "Resotore" button to get my windows and tabs back, but this is not a very clean solution.

Anyone have a better idea of how to achieve the effect of restoring application windows and tabs to a previous state after system reboot?

Thanks.

---

EDIT:

The behavior I'm asking for is application-specific and the place where the "Save Desktop Layout upon Quitting" functionality can be enabled varies from application to application. However, in Firefox 34.0.5 to use this setting one must enable it in `Menu icon -> General -> When Firefox starts: Show my windows and tabs from last time -> OK".

Regards.

Comment: This is built into Firefox.  When you quit, you should get a dialog box asking if you want to save the session.  If you do, the next time you open Firefox, all of the tabs are there as you left them.  This has been part of all recent versions.

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/restore-previous-session